How to handle focus change and onTap on ListTile item simultaneously in Flutter without using Future.delayed?
I have created a custom SearchDropdown widget in Flutter, which includes a TextFormField and a dropdown list of items. When the text field gains or loses focus, the dropdown list should appear or disappear respectively. When an item in the dropdown list is tapped, it should be selected, and the dropdown should hide.
Currently, I am using Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 700)) in the _handleFocusChange method to delay hiding the dropdown. This is because when a user taps (selects) an item from the dropdown list, only _handleFocusChange is called, and the tap is not registered immediately. By using a delay, I can handle both the tap and the focus change. However, this approach feels hacky and unreliable.
How can I handle the focus change and item selection in the dropdown without using Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 700)) in _handleFocusChange? What is the best practice to achieve this functionality in Flutter?
Here are the relevant parts of my code:
class SearchDropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<SearchDropdownItem> items;
  final Function(String) onTextChanged;
  final Function(dynamic) onItemSelected;
  final String selectedTextValue;
  final String? Function(String?)? validator;
  final String? headerText;

  const SearchDropdown({
    super.key,
    required this.items,
    required this.onTextChanged,
    required this.onItemSelected,
    required this.selectedTextValue,
    this.headerText,
    this.validator,
  });

  @override
  _SearchDropdownState createState() => _SearchDropdownState();
}

class _SearchDropdownState extends State<SearchDropdown> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  bool _isFocused = false;
  bool _isShowDropdown = false;
  OverlayEntry? _overlayEntry;
  final LayerLink _layerLink = LayerLink();

  void _onTextChanged() {
    widget.onTextChanged(_controller.text);
  }

  void _clearText() {
    _controller.clear();
    _onTextChanged();
    _handleItemSelected("", null);
  }

  void _handleItemSelected(String title, dynamic value) {
    _controller.text = title;
    widget.onItemSelected(value);
    _focusNode.unfocus(); // Remove focus when item is selected
    setState(() {
      _isShowDropdown = false; // Hide the dropdown when item is selected
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.text = widget.selectedTextValue;
    _controller.addListener(_onTextChanged);
    _focusNode.addListener(_handleFocusChange);
  }

  void _handleFocusChange() {
    if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _isFocused = true;
          _isShowDropdown = true;
        });
      }
    } else {
      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 700), () {
        if (mounted && !_focusNode.hasFocus) {
          setState(() {
            _isFocused = false;
            _isShowDropdown = false;
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }

  void _showDropdown() {
    if (_overlayEntry != null) {
      _overlayEntry!.remove();
    }
    _overlayEntry = _createOverlayEntry();
    Overlay.of(context).insert(_overlayEntry!);
  }

  void _removeDropdown() {
    if (_overlayEntry != null) {
      _overlayEntry!.remove();
      _overlayEntry = null;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry() {
    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    var size = renderBox.size;

    return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => Positioned(
        width: size.width,
        child: CompositedTransformFollower(
          link: _layerLink,
          showWhenUnlinked: false,
          offset: Offset(0, size.height),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surfaceContainer,
              border: Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface),
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(UIConstants.radius),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(UIConstants.radius),
              ),
            ),
            child: Material(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surfaceContainer,
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(UIConstants.radius),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(UIConstants.radius),
              ),
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200, minHeight: 0),
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  children: widget.items.map((item) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(item.title),
                      onTap: () {
                        _handleItemSelected(item.title, item.value);
                      },
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_isShowDropdown) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        _showDropdown();
      });
    } else {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        _removeDropdown();
      });
    }
    return CompositedTransformTarget(
      link: _layerLink,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          if (widget.headerText != null) ...[
            Text(widget.headerText ?? "", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleSmall?.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            const SizedBox(height: 5),
          ],
          TextFormField(
            controller: _controller,
            focusNode: _focusNode,
            validator: widget.validator,

.
.
.
.
.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Can't you use DropdownMenu instead?

@DhafinRayhan That's exactly what I'm trying to do, and I feel a little ashamed that I didn't find it. However, it's a relatively new widget and contains multiple issues with changing styles. Thank you so much anyway
